# Is it possible to share C++ classes between R-Packages?

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

We are having a rather large simulation written in C++ using Rcpp. We would like to refactor the code and put some of the C++ classes it uses in separate packages as we would like to use these classes also in the C++ code of other packages.
Is it possible to do this?

I've seen the // [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]] attribute, but in my understanding this only works for functions returning objects which can be interpreted by R. Rcpp modules can expose C++ classes to R, but it is also possible to expose the C++ classes to other C++ code?

Comment: Any reason not to have the class definitions in header file(s) in `inst/include`? Then other packages can use that code.

Comment: Easiest if you use a header-only approach as @duckmayr already said. If you need linking it gets *much* harder as R can only share C-level function calls between packages.

Comment: Maybe it helps to step back a little. You could think of RcppArmadillo doing what you plan to do---and it is used by 678 (!!) other CRAN packages.  Similarly BH offers Boost headers, the Stan econsystem has a header package and on and on.  But not one offers cross-package linking because in general ... we cannot do that.  But if you come back here (or to the rcpp-devel list) with a bit more "meat on the bone" I am sure we can help a little.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This will indeed solve the problem. If this is the most viable solution, then we will just put the implementation into the header files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There are a few ways. The easiest is if the C++ library is header-only as it can be embedded within `inst/include` as @duckmayr pointed out.

A scaled down example of header-only inclusion can be found here:

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-shared-cpp-functions

---

On another note, if the code should be shared within the same package between `.cpp` files, then another approach is to use header files within `src/` next to the `.cpp` files. An example of this can be found here:

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-headers-src

If you need sub-folders within the `src/` directory, then that is a bit more involved for a single package.

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-headers-subdirs